# Cauchy problem for $|y'(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, cauchy-problem

I need a check with the following exercise:

> Let $w: [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ with $w(0)=0$ and $w(y)>0$ a continuous function. Let $y:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ a $C^1$ function with the property
>
> \begin{cases}
> |y'(x)| \leq w(y(x)) \\
> y(0)=0
> \end{cases}
>
> for all $x \geq0$
>
> Show that if $\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{w(y)}=+\infty$, then $y(x)=0$ for all $x \geq0$

---

Here's my attempt:

From the Cauchy problem I find, for all $x\geq0$: $$-w(y(x))\leq y'(x) \leq w(y(x))$$

Let $ c \geq 0$: from the rightmost part: $$\int_0^c\frac{y'(x)}{w(y(x))}dx \leq c$$

which is equivalent to (setting $\phi=y(x)$) $$\int_0^{y(c)}\frac{d \phi}{w(\phi)} \leq c$$

If $y(c)>1$, then I obtain $$\int_0^{1}\frac{d \phi}{w(\phi)} + \int_1^{y(c)}\frac{d \phi}{w(\phi)} \leq c$$ By assumption, the first term is $+\infty$, which implies a contradiction  ($\infty \leq c$). Therefore it has to be $y(c) < 1$.

From the other condition, I obtain:

$$\int_0^{y(c)}\frac{d \phi}{w(\phi)} \geq-c (<0)$$

which is always satisfied. I don't know how to continue in order to show that $y$ has to be $0$.

Comment: I don't think that this is true. Take $y(x) = \frac{x^2}{2(1+x^2)}.$ Then $|y'(x)| = \frac{|x|}{(1+x^2)^2} \leq \frac{|x|}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}} = \sqrt{2y(x)}$. Also $|y(x)|\leq 1/2$.


Letting $w(y):= \sqrt{2y}\cdot 1_{\{y\in[0,1/2]\}}+(y-1/2)\cdot 1_{\{y>1/2\}}$, we thus have that $|y'(x)|\leq w(y(x))$. Also it is clear that $\int_0^1 w(y)^{-1}dy = +\infty$. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere, but I think you need the stronger assumption that $\int_0^{\epsilon}w(y)^{-1}dy = +\infty$ for all $\epsilon$ (not just some $\epsilon$).

Comment: ...which would be true if (for instance) you added  the assumption that w is continuous on [0,1], since you’re assuming that w is positive except at zero.

Comment: @shalop I would guess that the condition OP wants is increasing + continuous cf https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Osgood_criterion

Comment: Thank, I forgot $w$ continuous, edited. Btw, am I on the right path?

Comment: Yes, once you know that $w$ is continuous, you are done. That's because $w$ is countinuous and strictly positive on $[\epsilon,1]$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Therefore it is bounded from below, so $1/w$ is bounded from above. Therefore $\int_\epsilon^1 w(y)^{-1}dy<\infty$ which means that $\int_0^{\epsilon}w(y)^{-1}dy=+\infty$, so now the same argument as you have written shows that $|y(x)|<\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary........

Comment: Thanks @shalop. I can't prove it formally: 

From 
$$\int_0^{\epsilon} w(y)^{-1} dy + \int_{\epsilon}^{y(x)} w(y)^{-1}dy  \leq x$$

I can't conclude $y(x) \leq \epsilon$ because the inequality does not hold. I note that if $y(x)=0$, then the lhs is $0$ and hence since $x \geq0$ I have the thesis, but I'm not using the other inequality. Could you please show me how to get to $|y(x)| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @andereBen It is literally the same exact proof as you wrote above, just replace $1$ by $\epsilon$ everywhere. Suppose there existed a $c$ such that $y(c) \geq \epsilon$.....

Comment: @shalop sorry, but even if $y(c)< \epsilon$, I have that the integral explode, leading to a contradiction, because I will still have the integral from $0$ to $\epsilon$.

Comment: No, the proof works. There is literally no difference compared to the proof you have given above. In the question statement, you can replace $1$ by $\epsilon$ in the integral. Thus, in the proof that you have given, you can replace $1$ by $\epsilon$ everywhere.

Comment: @shalop Thanks, so I have $y(x) \leq \epsilon$. In order to obtain $y(x)>-\epsilon$, I should use the other inequality, but I can't do that. What should I do?

Comment: Read the question again: $y$ is assumed to be non-negative.

Comment: Oh yes, so $y(x)< \epsilon$ and $y(x)>0$.... so $|y'(x)|< \epsilon$ and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, then it follows that $y(x)=0$. Actually, I'm not using the second inequality, right?

Comment: @shalop could you please confirm I'm not using the second inequality $w(y(x)) \leq y'(x)$? I'm still a bit puzzed.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you need the part that says $y'\ge -w(y)$.